# Convert char to int?

Tags: c++

I'm making a battleships game, so when I pass something such as "A10" into the coordinate function it needs to make column into letter and row into the number.

```
Coordinate(std::string coord = "A10")
    {
        char c = coord[0];
        col = c - 16;

        int r = atoi((coord.substr(1,2)).c_str());
        row = r-1;
    };
```

So in this example, passing A10 should make col = 0 (A=0,B=1,C=2) and row = 9.

The row equaling 9 seems to work but col equally 0 does not.

Comment: You could extend your class with a custom literal. I.e: `A10_C`. You should even check that the passed string is in the correct format and throw an exception otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to map the value of 'A' to zero?   Remember that characters are single-byte integers,

```
char c = std::toupper( coord[0] );
if( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' )
{
    col = c - 'A';
}
else
{
    // TODO: Invalid/error?
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It should be `col = c - 'A'` to get the integer for `A`.

Comment: What about for each letter though?

Comment: @RBowen: That code works for each letter, for `A` it returns 0 for `B` 1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you call character 'A' is just a funny name for the number 65 (its ASCII value).
According to [this ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), 'B' = 66, 'C' = 67 and so on. So what you should do is compute `int column = static_cast<int>(coord[0] - 'A')`.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal value for `A (0x41)` is `65`, so you'd get 49 with your current maths. `col = c - 65` should give you the desired behaviour.